# Latex: Error in python module TEX

Tags: python, pdf, latex, tex

I do experiments in working with Latex and converting text to pdf. Latex figured using PyLatex module, but there is a problem with the printing of Unicode. I found the only way out is to use the Python module "TEX". But again there is some problem I can not solve. In carrying out my program to get Linux Terminal displays error:

```
sergen-pc:~$ python /home/sergen/PythonExp/latex.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergen/PythonExp/latex.py", line 27, in <module>
    tex.convert('/home/sergen/PythonExp/full.tex', 'tex', 'pdf', max_runs=3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tex.py", line 149, in convert
    raise ValueError(log)
ValueError: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex 2016.5.1)  20 OCT 2016 20:03
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/tmp/tex-temp-UzNg43/texput.tex
(/tmp/tex-temp-UzNg43/texput.tex)
! Emergency stop.
<*> /tmp/tex-temp-UzNg43/texput.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I can not understand what is the reason, or in the folder 'tmp' which tex refuses to read/write, whether in the guts of the tex module? If you know another Python module to convert the files to PDF,  I will be happy to try it.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using PyLaTeX instead of just using the `pdflatex` command line tool?

Comment: Yes, I write program with Python, therefor  pylatex is convenient for this purpose. Pylatex can make PDF from python , but can`t work with Unicode.

Comment: Can you post or link to a gist with `texput.tex`?

Comment: No, I can`t. The folder /tmp/tex-temp-UzNg43 is not existed, more preciesly it disappears immediately after creation.   @Eli

Answer (score 0):

Solved. When using the module, I pointed out the path to the file to convert, and it was necessary to extract its contents, and to give the module.